# How can I fix this error in Fiddler: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer, fiddler

For some reason I cannot monitor my asp.net page's request/responses to my local host in IE 8.0.

I use fiddler and I modified he url as this -by adding a dot before the semicolon-

http://localhost.:52749/JQuery/Chapter16-AJAX/PersonEditor.aspx

I get this error:

[Fiddler] Connection to localhost. failed.
Exception Text: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:52749

Thanks

Comment: Is the JavaScript also running on `localhost`?

Answer (score 6):

O.K. I have found how to work around this.

Go to Fiddler Options. Under General tab uncheck this:

'Enable IPv6 (If available)'

Then as usual add modify the URL that requests your files from your localhost by putting a dot after 'localhost' text.

It works!

Comment: So you don't have to mess around with the Rules in Fiddler at all as per the link in my answer?

Comment: @Martin Smith : Anyway, thank you for the link; it is useful information.

Comment: @pencilCake What does "Then as usual add modify the URL that requests your files from your localhost by putting a dot after 'localhost' text." mean?

Comment: @pencilCake You should mark this as the correct answer when you can. It works with mobile connections as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to just use http://ipv4.fiddler:52749 as your URL.